# Makefile forward the target name to docker run command

Tags: docker, makefile

I am trying to write a simple Makefile that forwards the target it was called with to docker run command. There is a dependency that builds a docker file and this dependency creates a dummy .docker-build file to make sure the build of docker image only runs once (not sure if I am following the norm/conversion here ...)

The problem is if the user types `make` without any target name then `$@` is equal to literal "Makefile" and I want to change that to "all" when calling the docker run command. But it doesn't work for some reason and code always goes to else block.

```
NAME=program1
.PHONY: all
.docker-build:
    docker build . -t ${NAME}
    echo "" > .docker-build

clean:
    docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
    docker image rm -f ${NAME}
    rm -r .docker-build

%: .docker-build
ifeq ($($@),"Makefile")
    docker run ${NAME} make all
else
    docker run ${NAME} make $@
endif
```

Comment: Is there more to the Makefile than this?  If this is literally the whole Makefile, would a shell script (that `docker run --rm image-name make "${1:-all}"`) be a better match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is...

- There is file named `Makefile`

You cannot use an existing filename as a target. Try this

```sh
touch clean
make clean
make all
```

Your `Makefile` has a target named `clean`, but may not work. The target `all` defined as `.PHONY` target, so it works.

If you really want to work as you intend, try this:

```
NAME=program1
.PHONY: all Makefile
.docker-build:
    docker build . -t ${NAME}
    echo "" > .docker-build

clean:
    docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
    docker image rm -f ${NAME}
    rm -r .docker-build

%: .docker-build
    docker run ${NAME} make $@

Makefile:
    docker run ${NAME} make all
```